# How can we check if a paired bluetooth low energy(ble) device is active or not?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect a ble device to my android device. I am able to scan for the ble device and pair it. However, when I try to check if the paired device is active or not, it is unpairing the ble device and then scanning again.

Is there an api available to check for the status of paired ble devices?

Comment: Answer for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308591/how-to-check-bluetooth-connection-state-with-paired-device-in-android

Comment: If you want to check if the pair devices is active, below is the link that worked for me.Visit this <https://stackoverflow.com/a/4716715/5602666>

Comment: @Alka Could you please help me with how you pair a BLE device to your android app? Cos I can scan the BLE device but cannot pair it.